# How to handle three functions with celery in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, celery

I'm having a three function in my django site views but I can only run one. I have never used celery, can you help me to transform this into the celery tasks?

As you can see, I want to save document which is uploaded by user, and then I want to do some pandas stuff with that file, and after that I want to show pandas stuff in html page.

This is forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

This is views.py

```
def save_exls(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            return redirect('html_exls')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    context = {'documents': documents, 'form': form,}
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)


def pandas_exls(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            output = io.BytesIO()
            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
            dfs = pd.read_excel(newdoc, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
            for name, df in dfs.items():
                #pandas stuff
                done.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
            output.seek(0)
            response = HttpResponse(
                output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
            return response
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form})


def html_exls(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            output = io.BytesIO()
            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
            dfs = pd.read_excel(newdoc, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
            for name, df in dfs.items():
                #pandas stuff for html 
                done.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)

            html = done.to_html()
            print(html)
            output.seek(0)
            response = HttpResponse(
                output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
            return response
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form})
```

This is html file, list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Django site</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url "pandas_exls" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>

            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
        </form>
        <br/>
            {{html|safe}}
        

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just have to combine these 3 functions in one. And let celery run this `[big]` function.

Comment: If I make it in one, there are errors. Any examples?

Comment: I have found similar project, but it has been organized differently, https://github.com/ebysofyan/django-celery-progress-sample

Comment: Here you're returning the response, with Celery processing the files asynchronously, you cannot allow users to directly download from the view. You'd need some kind of mechanism to store the file on server and let the users know when the task finishes. then they can download from your server.

Comment: I noticed you gave my answer the bounty, you might also want to select my answer as the accepted answer, and upvote.

Comment: @JensTimmerman Yes, bounty was getting to expire so I gave it for your answer. Did not have time to test it, that's why i did not mark it as accepted and up vote, I might have sub questions when I test it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [task_api](https://django-task-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html) for this, this is a django project that keeps track of the functions and provides some javascript to poll the backend for a change and updates when the functions are done running.
It does not yet seem to support file parameters, but you could save the file first, and then in javascript call the next method to operate on that file once saved, and display progress.

I would write 3 endpoints, 1 to upload the file, using the form, then 1 ajax endpoint you call in javascript to process the file, this will return when it is done, at which point you can redirect to the 3rd endpoint which will download the file.

e.g.
views.py

```py
                                                             
from task_api.tasks import Task                                                                                          
from task_api.params import IntParameter, StringParameter   

                                                                                                                         
class Pandas(Task):                                                                                             
    name = 'pandas'                                                                                             
    inputs = {                                                                                                           
        'documentid': IntParameter(),                                                                                     
                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                    
    outputs = {'output': StringParameter()}                                                                              
                                                                                                                         
    def run(self, documentid):                                                                                  
                                                                                                                         
        self.progress = 0                                                                                                
        output = io.BytesIO()
        newdoc = Document.objects.get(id=documentid)
        dfs = pd.read_excel(newdoc.docfile, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
        for name, df in dfs.items():
            #pandas stuff
            self.progress += 1 # update progress so we can show something to user in javascript                                                                                            
            done.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
        output.seek(0)
        Document.done = True
        Document.output = output
        Document.save()
        return documentid

# configure /download in your urls.py to point to this view with documentid parameter
def download_exls(request, documentid):
    response = HttpResponse(
    Document.objects.get(id=documentid).output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
    return response
     
def save_exls(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():

        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'documentid': newdoc.id}), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    context = {'documents': documents, 'form': form,}
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

and in your list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Django site</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'django-task-api.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function runtask(task, documentid, progressdivname) {
            TaskAPI.run(task, documentid, function(json) {
                if (json.target === null || json.progress === null) {
                    return false
                }
                document.getElementById(progressdivname).innerHTML = 'Progress: ' + json.progress + ' / ' + json.target
            })
            .then(function(json) {
                # panda's is done, download doc
                window.location = '/download/' + json.outputs.documentid;
    })
            return false
        }

$(document).ready(function (e) {
 $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
         url: "/upload",
   type: "POST",
   data:  new FormData(this),
   contentType: false,
         cache: false,
   processData:false,
   beforeSend : function()
   {
    //$("#preview").fadeOut();
    $("#err").fadeOut();
   },
   success: function(documentid)
      {

     // process uploaded file.
runtask('pandas', {'documentid': documentid}, 'progress')
    }
,
     error: function(e) 
      {
    $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
      }          
    });
 }));
});
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url "pandas_exls" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>

            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <div id="progress"></div>
        

    </body>
</html>
```

Be advised, this will allow anyone to download any file, just based on the id, you will probably want to add some authentication checks if this is not intended, you might also want to do some garbage collection and cleanup because this will keep all documents in your database.